# phpseclib 2.0.12 - SFTP login failed but no error

Tags: phpseclib

I've installed phpseclib 2.0.12 with composer. I am running PHP 7.0.30.

I cannot log into an SFTP site using:

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/vendor/autoload.php");
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', SFTP::LOG_COMPLEX);
$sftp = new SFTP($ftp_server);
echo("<pre>");
if (!$sftp->login($ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)) {
    print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
    echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
    exit('Login Failed');
} else {
    echo("login worked");
}
echo("</pre>");
```

The output is simply:

```
Array
(
)
Login Failed
```

Why is logging not displaying anything at all? How can I see what is failing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX);` and `$sftp->getLog();` instead. `NET_SFTP_LOGGING` only enables logging at the SFTP layer, which is only established *after* you've successfully authenticated.

Similarily, I'd do `print_r($sftp->getErrors());` instead of `print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());`.

Comment: Thanks... that worked, although I had to also add: "use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;" which isn't required for SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I encountered a related issue and the password had a backslash in it.  We changed our variable to use single quote marks instead of double and authentication worked.  I suspect somewhere it was being treated as escape character.  Perhaps this will helps someone save a few hours troubleshooting.